# How to avoid nesting getJSON for two separate data sources?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have the following:

```
$.getJSON("firsturl", function(source1) {
   $.getJSON("secondurl", function(source2) {
      // I have source 1 and source 2 data here!
   }
}
```

What is a better way of getting data from both sources.. and doing something with both of them without nesting all these $.getJSON calls?

Comment: are u dependant on the `source1` to call `secondurl`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: @passionateCoder No I am not. They are mutually exclusive. But I need both source1 and source2 before I do anything else.

Comment: $.when will give you a promise object that resolves once both deferred/promise objects have resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when($.getJSON("/firsturl"), $.getJSON("secondurl")).done(function(result1, result2){
  /* result1 and result2 are arguments resolved for the
      page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively. 
      each argument is an array with the following 
      structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ] */
});
```

Comment: So, your `source1` is `result1[0]`, and `source2` is `result2[0]`

Comment: Here's an example using deferred objects. Deferred objects are just objects that wait for something async to finish, so you can resolve them with any data. In the example of getJSON, the resulting data and xhr stuff will be passed. In this example, I'm just using numbers. http://jsfiddle.net/8KKtq/

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery Deferred objects with `$.when`:

```
var first = $.getJSON("firstUrl");

var second = $.getJSON("secondUrl");

$.when(first, second).done(function(firstResult, secondResult) {
  // do stuff;

});
```